# Can't get the jTab custom chord syntax to render!

Tags: support, status-completed, jtab

Wth this [answer](https://music.stackexchange.com/a/6131/1344), I tried to use jTab's custom chord syntax ([ref](http://jtab.tardate.com/)) to display a normal chord shape with non-standard fingering. Hunting around in questions tagged `chords`, [the only example I found](https://music.stackexchange.com/revisions/6d08a0c6-b9fc-4eb4-ac59-70cc40fb79f1/view-source) just used the bare names and let jTab implicitly select the standard shape.

So here's all the ways I tried:

- In a code block

  %3/3.2/2.0/0.0/0.3/4.3/4[G]
- In a code block with no appended display name

  %3/3.2/2.0/0.0/0.3/4.3/4
- In a div tag

%3/3.2/2.0/0.0/0.3/4.3/4[G]

- In a div tag in a code block

  %3/3.2/2.0/0.0/0.3/4.3/4[G]

And I'm out of ideas. Help? Is this feature activated? Am I doing it wrong(ly)?

Comment: Earlier I was seeing strange errors in the revisions view -- there were things like `<div etc="">` shown on the staff.  I assumed it was a problem with Chrome beta since I didn't see it in FF, but maybe not.

Comment: I got the `<div>` tags from the jTab examples page. Even there, it suggested the effect should be merely cosmetic. I thought it might get processed differently and potentially *trigger* the "right" thing. I confess CSS scares me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We're currently on an older version of [jTab](http://jtab.tardate.com/) that doesn't support that particular custom chord syntax.

Never fear, though!  I'm pushing out the latest version of this awesome library, so your post should work soon.

Comment: Excellent news! Thank you.

Comment: Did this update happen yet? Could it be the cause of http://meta.music.stackexchange.com/questions/358/jtabs-not-working-for-me?rq=1

Comment: Yes, the update was pushed out when I answered this question.  [Your answer](http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/6125/how-to-improve-train-pinky-dexterity-for-guitar-playing-after-long-absence/6131#6131) is rendering fine for me in FireFox 13.0.1 and Chrome 19.0.1084.56.  I doubt it's the cause of your Iceweasel issue.