# jTab needs to render in Markdown preview

Tags: bug, feature-request, jtab

I didn't find any information about special diagram notations in the FAQ... I tried to put the string names next to the guitar neck diagram in [this question](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/6822/song-analysis-foo-fighters-arlandria), but this produced chord diagrams which weren't visible in the preview.

Like this:

```
E - - - o o - o - O
B - - - o o - o
G - - - o - O - 
D - - - o - o o
A - - - O - o o 
E - - - - - - -
```

Here the chord diagrams are not shown; I suppose because the feature is not active on the meta site?

So, where are these features documented, and could you please fix the preview? Thanks.

Comment: Similarly, it would be less confusing if jTab and <pre> were mentioned on the [editing help page](https://music.stackexchange.com/editing-help). I had to track down one of these meta q/a's to get the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 6):

Setting preview issues aside for a moment, you can find tutorials and the like here: http://jtab.tardate.com/. We don't keep a copy of their docs.

Comment: I think the OP is specifically requesting that jTab be added to the post preview so that we don't have instances of people using the syntax by accident only to find their post comes out completely different from what they expect... This would also be very useful: http://meta.music.stackexchange.com/q/240/133

Comment: @NReilingh jTab takes over all of your "code" blocks, right?

Comment: I never figured out exactly how it works since I don't answer many guitar questions; I just put everything in `<pre>` tags if I want to be safe about it. But yeah, it is a bit overzealous from what I see of other peoples' butchered posts.

Answer (score 5):

We really need a jTab preview during editing.  And we need the jTab implementation to be fixed.

My answer at [Fighting against the F Chord](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/44938/fighting-against-the-f-chord/45004#45004) took forever to edit without the graphics or syntax errors displayed during editing.  In fact, in Chrome, if I made a change to the jTab AND it was syntactically correct, I still had to refresh the display to see the jTab graphics.  Moreover, I couldn't get the three voicings to display in one block, I had to insert text between the 2nd and 3rd chord to get the chords to display.

Fretboard diagrams are extremely important in explaining guitar chord voicings.  Relatively few guitarists can map standard notation and fret location to actual chord voicings.

Answer (score 0):

See [my question here](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340/cant-get-the-jtab-custom-chord-syntax-to-render?rq=1). The first example shows how to use jTab's *custom chord* syntax.