# How do you force linebreaks with jTab?

Tags: discussion, support, jtab

In my answer here, [What are good warm-up exercises for guitarists?](https://music.stackexchange.com/a/9675/1344), I'd like each measure on a separate line so it's easier to infer the quarter note timing.

Anyone know how to do that?

Comment: I've solved this by making an image with MuseScore in standard notation. Since there's no upvotes, I say: VTC too localized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there's some way to hack it in, but I'll bet we'd sooner bump it into community wiki from repeated edits since there's no markdown preview.

Incidentally, please upvote: [jTab needs to render in Markdown preview](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/q/396/133).

If you want to try, I'd test out hiding nonprinting HTML or something between your lines of jTab. I think you just need to break up the `<pre>` or `<code>` tags that it is rendered in--right now all of your lines of jTab are getting sucked into them.

Comment: I tried it. It's ... uh ... *better*. :)