# What happened with the jTab support?

Tags: bug, status-completed, jtab

I've seen quesions where the jTab wasn't parsed, but the code is shown instead. I wasn't sure if it was due to some syntactic mistakes in the code, but now I saw an answer of my own, where it definitely worked before. Has something happened to this support? The question is tagged with guitar, don't know if that was made a requisite for jTab rendering, I think that was suggested at some point.

https://music.stackexchange.com/a/15229/8682

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We switched to a new way of minifying Javascript files, and then helpfully excluded all third-party scripts we use from that process. :)

A fix is rolling out right now, so jTab should be working again shortly.

Answer (score 3):

The guitar tag requirement was suggested but never implemented. I'll bet this happened during the recent backend/network skin update. The bug tag should get picked up by an SE associate; hopefully they can reimplement it only on the guitar-tagged questions this time!

**EDIT:**

Oh, and add it to the live preview, too!

[Guitar tab plugin (jTab) should be active only in questions tagged [guitar]](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/q/240/133)

[jTab needs to render in Markdown preview](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/q/396/133)

Comment: Not actually related to the meta split. :) I'm fixing the immediate issue with jTab not loading at all, but the per-tag or preview support will have to wait.

Comment: Oh, I wasn't thinking the meta split, but I thought the header bar got a UI overhaul not too long ago. Thanks!